# Name for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, statistics

I'm trying to figure out if there is a proper or commonly accepted name for this particular function (`f`).

```
float clamp(float min, float max, float v)
{
    if (v < min) return min;
    else if (v > max) return max;
    else return v;
}

float f(float min, float max, float v)
{
    float t = (v - min) / (max - min);

    return clamp(0.0, 1.0, t);
}
```

Comment: Closest I can think of is Excel's "PERCENTRANK" function, though it doesn't do the clamping bit. Your `f` would be equivalent to `PERCENTRANK([min, max], clip(min, max, f))`... if Excel had a clip/clamp function.

Comment: What does it do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is sometimes called "0-1 normalization" or "feature scaling".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28statistics%29)

The entire function f() is a [Piecewise function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_function), which consists of 3 domains, defined separately for

1. v <= min
2. v is between min and max, and
3. v >= max.

The primary function is the normalization function when v is between min and max.  The other two functions just limit the [range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_%28mathematics%29) or [codomain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) of the function.

Piecewise functions are used often in mathematics to make the whole function [continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) over a larger domain or to handle special cases like divide by zero, which the original poster might want to handle when min == max.

And what does the function do?
Creates a function f(x) where f(min) returns 0.0, f(max) returns 1.0, and f(v) rescales the input v from 0.0 to 1.0 linearly. Anything less than min maps to 0.0; anything more than max maps to 1.0.

One application of this is to calculate the percentile of a data samples (but from 0.0 to 1.0 vice 0 to 100).

Comment: Agreed, seems the closest. Of course, this suffers from the same minor criticism I left in the comments regarding the PERCENTRANK function: for it to work, it requires that `v` be between `min` and `max`, which is by default true when considering samples, but which is explicitly untrue of cmbassnet's question.